# Modifying outgoing android screen

Tags: android, screenshot

Is there a way I can change what goes out as TV-Out on android (I'm using a Nexus 4). When I connect the phone to a TV I want to send a different image than what is on the phone screen. I have a rooted device and one way to do this might be to somehow modify the FrameBuffer in /dev/graphics/fd0 since that is presumably where the information goes from? Since I want a modified image of the screen image , another way could be to send the current screen image periodically to the PC, process it and send the signal to TV  - but this is a very roundabout way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Nexus 4, buy a Miracast wireless bridge for your TV -- I have had luck with [this Netgear unit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00904JILO). Then, you can use `DisplayManager` and `Presentation` to display different content on the TV than is on the Nexus 4. No rooting required.

Comment: The Miracast Wireless Bridge is for connecting the TV-out to the TV? I'm using Slimport+HDMI - is this different from that somehow? Also, could you elaborate a bit on how to do this using Display Manager and Presentation - any examples?

Comment: Ah ok, so the netgear thing is wireless - well I want support for Projectors as well which might not have wireless capability but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Stat: "well I want support for Projectors as well which might not have wireless capability" -- the Netgear device provides wireless capability to TVs, projectors, and other HDMI devices. "I'm using Slimport+HDMI" -- if that works, great. I wasn't aware that the Nexus 4 supported that. "Also, could you elaborate a bit on how to do this using Display Manager and Presentation - any examples?" -- see http://www.slideshare.net/commonsguy/secondscreen-support-in-android-42 and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Presentation and https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if the specific second screen feature  is supported by the Slimport. My projector does not have wifi capability. Would it be possible to connect an HDMI cable to the Netgear devivce?

Comment: @Stat7: "Would it be possible to connect an HDMI cable to the Netgear devivce?" -- yes. That is the entire point of that Netgear device. I have successfully used it with a television and with an HDMI switchbox connected to a projector.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that this will give me second screens for my app - But what I want is to run a background app which takes the current display every second (whatever app is displayed on phone) modifies it and that modified image should be displayed on the second screen. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @Stat7: That's beyond what `Presentation` can do. `Presentation` is designed for the foreground activity, as `Presentation` inherits from `Dialog`. I haven't the foggiest notion of what you want is readily doable, rooted or otherwise.